# Which UIWebView has the load request?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiwebview, shouldstartload

So my class has two different UIWebView objects (one is a menu the other is for content). Let's call them UIWebView "A" and UIWebView "B"

In my shouldStartLoadWithRequest how do i determine which UIWebView a link was called from?
Was it "A" or "B"?
I thought i could just check a property like "title" or "name" so i looked through the documentation but no such luck.

I'm looking for something like this...

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
NSLog(@"WebView is... %@",[webView title]);
}
```

If i log the entire webView i get a large hash but no reference to the original name i gave it in my IBOutlet. Hope this makes sense.

Also, could someone point me to how i would find this kind of properties in the documentation because it seems like a pretty basic thing i am trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just test if the `webView` parameter passed to that method is equal to the ivars you declared.

For example, if the ivars for the IBOutlets are named `webViewA` and `webViewB`:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    if (webView == webViewA)
        NSLog(@"webview A wants to load %@", request);
    else
        if (webView == webViewB)
            NSLog(@"webview B wants to load %@", request);
        else
            NSLog(@"some other webview wants to load %@", request);

    return YES;
}
```

Alternatively, you can also set the `tag` property of each web view either in IB or code to some non-zero values (say 10 and 20) and check the value of `webView.tag` in the delegate method.